# Adding CollectionView with Cell into a .xib file for a Cell of TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `TableView` in my storyboard, which has custom cell defined in `.xib` file. I would like to add horizontal `CollectionView` with defined number of cells into it. When i drag-n-drop the Collection view into my `.xib` cell file, it has gray color but I'm able to add it inside without problem. Problem comes, when I try to add cell inside the view. When I just drag-n-drop it literally nothing happens. How I'm supposed to add it there please?

[image: photo]

Comment: check this link I hope this will solve your problem. https://medium.com/@aestusLabs/adding-a-uicollectionviews-to-a-custom-uitableviewcell-xib-tutorial-swift-4-xcode-9-2-1ec9ce4095d3